# Squarespace Local Development doesnt seem to want to work

Tags: server, terminal, development-environment, squarespace

I am following the developers.squarespace.com documentation and I am trying to use a local dev environment to make my static website into a squarespace template. As far as getting the server started, everything is working fine until I get to the point of installing the squarespace server to my system. To beging, I use this command in my Mac's terminal:

```
npm install -g @squarespace/server
```

After I enter this, everything once again seems to be working correctly because I am met with this (which doesn't show any errors as I have seen for others):

```
 Executing: npm run bundle

> @squarespace/server@1.1.2 bundle /Users/Squid/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@squarespace/server
> node scripts/bundlejre.js --accept --clear -tz -j 8u131 -o build/distributions/runtimes/jre

Bundling compatible JRE (This may take a while)

> @squarespace/server@1.1.2 cleanupscript /Users/Squid/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@squarespace/server
> node scripts/execif.js --os=win32 --exists=build node scripts/vetolines.js build/distributions/local-developer/bin/run.bat #!

+ @squarespace/server@1.1.2
updated 1 package in 56.891s
```

Following that, I clone my site into a folder on my desktop from git and then navigate to the folder in terminal. At this point, I attempt to start the Dev Server, by running the following command(with the "site-name" changed to my site's name:

```
squarespace-server https://site-name.squarespace.com
```

**My problem begins here, I am met with the following response from the terminal:**

```
-bash: squarespace server: command not found
```

My mac doesn't recognize the server, even though I found the folder manually on my computer (but I don't know what to do with it). 
So far I have attempted a couple troubleshooting methods:

1. I have a trial site so I tried to use the --auth flag as suggested on the documentation.
2. I restarted the whole process, so I removed all node and squarespace related files from my system and started again.
3. After looking online for answers, I installed [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to make sure that I am installing node and git correctly to my system.
4. Finally, I have attempted to change permissions for npm (but I'm not sure that I did this part correctly or not since I don't receive any permission errors).

Also, thank you so much for reading through all this. I just really wanted to make sure you all understood where I was at in this whole process.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this by adding an export path to your profile.

Open the terminal

Enter the following command

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
```

(this creates the bash profile)

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

(this opens the bash profile you just created)

Your bash profile will open in a text editor.

Add the following line, then save:

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

Restart terminal and try using the command again. < This part is important. If you don't restart your terminal it won't recognise the profile.

https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally